# Sum two series the STD way

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two `std::vector<double>` of the same size which represents different series.

Is there any clean way to sum those vectors using STD ?

Something similar to `std::accumulate` but works on two series.

Comment: What's your desired output given `{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6}` as input? 21? `{5, 7, 9}`? `{6, 15}`?

Comment: Assuming you want to calculate `sum(A) + sum(B)`, any attempt to STL-ify beyond two accumulations and an addition just adds complexity and potentially reduces performance.  If you might need to handle *N* vectors, it's worth doing something more concise, but for just 2, use `+`.

Comment: @T.C. Your first example is correct. The second example is irrelevant because as I said it is guaranteed that the series of the same size.

Comment: @MooseBoys: I'd upvote that as an answer....

Comment: @AlejandroFreeman the second example is not irrelevant at all. 6and 15 are the sums of the elements of each vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend just using two `accumulate`s and adding the result. It's more readable.

If you really insist, since your vectors are of the same length, you can abuse `std::inner_product`:

```
double result = std::inner_product(veca.begin(), veca.end(), vecb.begin(),
                                   0.0, std::plus<double>(), std::plus<double>());
```

Comment: I don't entirely agree. The version in my answer using ``boost::range::join`` is arguably clearer (at least to me, perhaps it's personal). It will not change the complexity or even running time for large vectors.

Comment: @AmiTavory If you are dragging in the boost dependency, why not just `boost::accumulate` and skip the extra variable? Also, I'm not sure about the performance characteristics here without doing some measurements; incrementing the iterator for the joined range is probably more expensive due to the need to check when the first range ends and the second begins.

Comment: Oops, I absolutely take it back about the performance. Other points good too.

Answer (score 3):

Following are two answers, depending on whether the output should be the vector that is the sum of the vectors, or the scalar sum of them (in which case, I'm not sure why it is relevant that they are of equal length).

**Vector Sum**

How about the [binary version of `std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/):

```
std::vector<double> res(lhs.size());

std::transform(
     lhs.begin(), lhs.end(),
     rhs.begin(),
     res.begin(),
     [](double l, double r){return l + r;});
```

Note that instead of the lambda, you can use [`std::plus<double>()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/) from `functional`.

**Scalar Sum**

Either sum like

```
auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs), 0.0) + 
     std::accumulate(std::begin(rhs), std::end(rhs), 0.0);
```

or use [`boost::range::join`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/range/join.hpp):

```
auto both = boost::range::join(lhs, rhs);
auto sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(both), std::end(both), 0.0);
```

Comment: This is not what I was talking about. The output should be a number not a vector. For example you have these series: {1,2}, {3,4} output: 10 not {4,6}.

Comment: Updated for the second interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple and just call twice accumulate, you can add it in a separate function that handles it for you. 
It's more readable and everyone will be able to understand it at the first glance.

```
namespace util{
  double accumulate(std::vector<double>& a, std::vector<double>& b)
  {
    return std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0.) + std::accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), 0.);
  }
}
```